# flutter scalable ocr flash light method

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i want to implement a flashlight feature in my app with a scalable ocr package, is there any means to use flashlight in this package?

i have tried FlashMode.torch
but doesn't work

or is there any other package that I can use with scalability and flashlight features?